# Appium ios - Unknown device or simulator UDID

Tags: appium-ios

I am facing the following issue while running test-script on real device(iPhone 7).
After saw that log, I try to solve this issue, but I stuck here (Check the screenshot)

Environment - 
Appium - 1.8.0-beta3
Device - iphone 7 (OS - 10.3.1)
mac OS - 10.13.2

```
Appium Log - 

[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.8.0-beta3  
[Appium] Non-default server args:  
[Appium]   port: 5488  
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:5488  
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}  
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []  
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.8.0-beta3","revision":null}}  
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 23 ms - 78   
    Attempt[1] to start appium server  
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}  
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []  
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.8.0-beta3","revision":null}}   
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 15 ms - 78  
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}  
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []  
[debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.8.0-beta3","revision":null}}    
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 15 ms - 78      
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"noReset":false,"clearSystemFiles":true,"newCommandTimeout":1200,"platformVersion":"10.3.1","automationName":"XCuiTest","bundleId":"--------","udid":"457187374caf18----------------------------------","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iOS"},"requiredCapabilities":{},"capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"noReset":false,"clearSystemFiles":true,"newCommandTimeout":1200,"platformVersion":"10.3.1","automationName":"XCuiTest","bundleId":"-----------","udid":"457187374caf18----------------------------------","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iOS"},"requiredCapabilities":{},"alwaysMatch":{"platformName":"iOS"},"firstMatch":[]}}      
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"noReset":false,"clearSystemFiles":true,"newCommandTimeout":1200,"platformVersion":"10.3.1","automationName":"XCuiTest","bundleId":"-----------","udid":"457187374caf18----------------------------------","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iOS"},{},{"desiredCapabilities":{"noReset":false,"clearSystemFiles":true,"newCommandTimeout":1200,"platformVersion":"10.3.1","automationName":"XCuiTest","bundleId":"-----------","udid":"457187374caf18----------------------------------","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iOS"},"requiredCapabilities":{},"alwaysMatch":{"platformName":"iOS"},"firstMatch":[]}]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1519049570375 (19:42:50 GMT+0530 (IST))   
[Appium] Could not parse W3C capabilities: 'deviceName' can't be blank. Falling back to JSONWP protocol.     
[Appium] Creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.68.0) session     
[Appium] Capabilities:    
[Appium]   noReset: false      
[Appium]   clearSystemFiles: true     
[Appium]   newCommandTimeout: 1200    
[Appium]   platformVersion: 10.3.1     
[Appium]   automationName: XCuiTest       
[Appium]   bundleId: -----------      
[Appium]   udid: 457187374caf18----------------------------------     
[Appium]   platformName: iOS     
[Appium]   deviceName: iOS     
[debug] [BaseDriver]     
[debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with MJSONWP desired capabilities: {"noReset":false,"clearSyst...   
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 431df073-2efd-4f7f-b9c6-9868cc1d87d6      
[debug] [XCUITest] Current user: 'test'    
[debug] [XCUITest] Xcode version set to '9.2'     
[debug] [XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to '11.2'    
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'xcodeDetailsRetrieved' logged at 1519049570723 (19:42:50 GMT+0530 (IST))     
[XCUITest] The 'idevice_id' program is not installed. If you are running a real device test it is necessary. Install with 'brew install libimobiledevice --HEAD'    
[debug] [XCUITest] Available devices:     
[XCUITest] Error: Unknown device or simulator UDID: '457187374caf18----------------------------------'
```

Comment: did you find any solution? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

On terminal run these commands

```
brew uninstall ideviceinstaller
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew unlink libimobiledevice && brew link libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD ideviceinstaller
brew unlink ideviceinstaller && brew link ideviceinstaller
```